# resize multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

The last two days I've been trying to get the resize vba to work.
I need 3 columns (Q,R,S) to be copied and pasted after column 19. This has to happen until the number of 3 column sets (i, copies of Q:S) is equal to the value in cell ("C18"), likewise, if the number of repeats of QRS is greater than the value in C18 the unnecessary copies should be deleted.
The resize worked fine when it was just one column but now that I try to get a set of 3 added or deleted it goes wrong..the number of copies is not equal to the value in ("C18") and the number of copies made or deleted is not constant when I rerun the sub.

Does anyone have a solution?

```
Sub resize()

Dim SLastCol As Long
Dim i As Long

i = Range("C18").Value * 3
SLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 19 


If SLastCol < i Then
    Columns("Q:S").EntireColumn.copy
   Columns("T").EntireColumn.Resize(, Abs(SLastCol - i)).Insert shift:=xlToRight
ElseIf SLastCol > i Then
    Columns("T:W").EntireColumn.Resize(, Abs(SLastCol - i)).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What range do you expect from `Columns("T:W").EntireColumn.Resize(, 3)`?

Comment: I am struggling to understand what exactly you try accomplishing and I am not sure that I understood. Please, try describing (in words, or placing two pictures) such a situation. What value to be considered in "C18"? And why should it be multiplied by 3? Is it mandatory that the last column in your real sheet to be processed to be larger then 19? Then try corelating the  numbers and mention the columns to be resize **as you want**. I asked about your expectation in the previous comment, because it will return the same as `Columns("T:T").EntireColumn.Resize(, 3)`. The range first column matters

Comment: well I want to make an input for new products. If there are 4 new entries (=Value C18)
Then I need a column for product specifications, one column for order date  and a column for shipping date (column Q,R,S) * 4.

Comment: So, let me check if my understanding is (now) correct: Placing **2 in "C18"** and put in clipBoard a range of **3 column**, the code should copy it twice, so it needs to **insert 6 columns**. If the range to be copied contains **4 columns*, it should insert/copy **8 such columns*. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: correct, But in this case it will always be 3 columns. The number of repeats is variable (C18).

Comment: So, even simpler... I still cannot understand why is necessary to calculate `SLastCol`, since the code should insert and copy starting from the column after the copied range and insert/copy it as many times as the value in "C8"... I will try posting a simplified code. If I missed something, please comment and explain what it does wrong...

Comment: True, but if the number in C18 goes down, the number of columns should also decrease by the same number*3, that's why I thought I had to look for the last column

Comment: So, you do  not **only** wont to insert **after the range to be copied**? Do you want, in some circumstances to insert columns **before the range**"? If so, in which circumstances to insert columns before the range to be copied? If the number there **goes down/up**, the code will multiply according to its value, but always **after the range**...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241243/discussion-between-user17269242-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will copy **all columns** in the range `colsRng`, as many times as is written in "C8":

```
Sub resizeColumnsCopy()
 Dim i As Long, colsRng As Range, lastCol As Long, rngDel As Range, arrCols, arrPrevCols
 
 'identify the previous processed columns and delete them, if any
 lastCol = cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 arrPrevCols = Range(cells(1, 20), cells(1, lastCol)).Value 'place the headers after column 20 in an array
 arrCols = Range("Q1:S1").Value 'do the same with the copied columns headers
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrPrevCols, 2) Step 3  'iterate in the larger array, from three to three columns
    If arrPrevCols(1, i) = arrCols(1, 1) Then    'finding the first column header
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
           Set rngDel = Range(cells(1, 19 + i), cells(1, 19 + i + 2)) 'create a range of the three involved columns
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, Range(cells(1, 19 + i), cells(1, 19 + i + 2))) 'careate a Union between the previous range and the next three
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete 'if cases of processed columns found, then delete the columns
 
 i = Range("C18").Value
 Set colsRng = Columns("Q:S")
    colsRng.Copy
    cells(1, colsRng.Column + colsRng.Columns.count).EntireColumn.resize(, i * colsRng.Columns.count).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

But, please edit your question and explain about the necessity of previous processed columns deletion. Otherwise, somebody else looking to my code will think that I recently hit my head...